# eventHandler, defining & accessing params (java Swing Netbeans)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, event-handling

in short: How do I get access to a param passed into a GUI constructor within eventHandler?

more details:
I am using NetBeans and Swing to write a Plugin in Java.  I have created a Jframe with a GUI which includes a JTextField.  The eventHandler for JTextField writes the value entered to a variable.  Within the eventHandler I want next to call a method() which uses this variable **and** another, which was passed into the GUI's constructor.

?? How can I gain access to this variable? NetBeans wont let me change the auto-generated eventHandler signature to include the GUI variable I need. This eventHandler code below.

This is week 3 of Java for me so apologies if this is very basic question
thank you
B
PS thank for site, it has already answered **many** other questions.

```
private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  // *** no edit allowed to signature (greyed by NetBeans)                                          
    System.out.println( "textField2: " +  jTextField1.getText() );
    String s = jTextField2.getText();
    try {
        numIter = Integer.parseInt(s.trim());
        testMethod(numIter, paramPassedIntoGUIconstructor); 
// ?? how to get paramPassedIntoGUIconstructor?? <<-- key question
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Cytoscape.getDesktop(),
                "That's not an integer!", "NumberFormatException",1);
    }
} // *** no edit allowed (greyed by NetBeans)
```

Comment: "NetBeans wont let me .." seems like a good case to put NetBrains aside and Learn *Java*.  Perhaps once you have learned enough Java you will be able to return to the automagic IDE and make it work for you, as opposed to it making you its dog.

Comment: @ Andrew. I couldn't agree more. But within a syllabus that has just 2 weeks 'taught' exposure & a 1 week assignment before rushing off to 'cover' the next topic as superficially as the last, there just isn't the time. Frustrating? You bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem, but you should be able to add a member variable:

```
private final Integer answer;
// Variables declaration - do not modify
...
// End of variables declaration
```

Initialize it in your constructor:

```
public MyClass(Integer iWantAccessToThis) {
    initComponents();
    answer = iWantAccessToThis;
}
```

Access it, *ad lib*:

```
private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    ...
    System.out.println(this.answer);
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks. I described the situation poorly. Your explanation lays the groundwork well to correct this. The variable I want to access was passed into the constructor as a parameter, rather than being assigned within it. thus public MyClass(OtherClass IwantAccessToThis){ ...

Comment: The required change is straightforward: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5039420/revisions

Comment: Thank you for the revision. That's ~kindof what I had arrived at in the end. But it looked like a hack, so I thought there must be a better way. Learning curve going exponential ... (-:

Comment: @bobox: That appearance may be an artifact of how the GUI code generator arranges things.

Answer (score 1):

As @trashgod noted, it just works. However, if you attempt to use `this` to reference a variable, (eg. `this.answer`) it will fail.

When the listener is executing, `this` refers to the instance of the listener. To reference your outer class, you need to qualify the access by prepending the class name like so: `Myclass.this.answer`.

The JLS refers to it as a [Qualified this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.4)

Comment: I would say _may_ fail. The member method `jTextField2ActionPerformed()` is called from an anonymous inner class, at which point `answer` is visible without qualification. Note also that the lexically enclosing class can be the class itself. In this case, `answer`, `this.answer` and `Myclass.this.answer` are equivalent.